# stuck on symfony2 for contact form

Tags: symfony, contact-form

I have problem with a contact form in symfony2 here is the code what i've done and what error do i get

```
<?php
// src/Aleksandar/IntelMarketingBundle/Resources/views/ContactType.php
namespace Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Resources\views;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;


class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'What\'s your name?',
                    'pattern'     => '.{2,}' //minlength
                )
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'So I can get back to you.'
                )
            ))
            ->add('subject', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'The subject of your message.',
                    'pattern'     => '.{3,}' //minlength
                )
            ))
            ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'placeholder' => 'And your message to me...'
                )
            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'name' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Name should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 2))
            ),
            'email' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Email should not be blank.')),
                new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid email address.'))
            ),
            'subject' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Subject should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 3))
            ),
            'message' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Message should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 5))
            )
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
?>
```

This is the code for the contact form which will be rendered in the view
no here is the code from my controller

```
<?php

namespace Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/contact", _name="contact")
 * @Template()
 */      

         public function contactAction()
    {

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
                ->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
                ->setTo('info@intelmarketing.es')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact.html.php',
                        array(
                            'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
                            'name' => $form->get('name')->getData(),
                            'message' => $form->get('message')->getData()
                        )
                    )
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your email has been sent! Thanks!');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );

    }


}
```

and here is the rooting

```
aleksandar_intel_marketing_contactpage:
    pattern:  /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:Default:contact }
```

now when i try to open the page its says the fallowing:

> "[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Route" in method
>   Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Controller\DefaultController::contactAction()
>   was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for
>   this annotation? 500 Internal Server Error - AnnotationException "

If any one knows what might be the problem please let me know

Answer (score 3):

As the error message states, you are missing a use statement on top of your controller file.

Simply add:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

on top of your class `DefaultController`.

You can then replace your routing with:

```
aleksandar_intel_marketing:
    resource: "@AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

This way, you are using the `@Route` annotation instead of the default `yml` way to declare your routes.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Comment: Okay it fix that problem thank you now something else come up

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Controller\ContactType' not found in C:\wamp\www\symfony\src\Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 38

Comment: Your are missing the a use statement on top of `DefaultContro‌​ller.php`. Add the following line to fix it: `use Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Form\Type\ContactType;`

Comment: Okay now it fix the error but its shows blank page... it wont show up the content on it

Comment: You will probably have better asking a new question with the new detailed issue.